# How to change your expansion pack after the recent update?

Tags: starcraft-2

The option in the "gameplay" settings is no longer available..

Comment: Can elaborate more on what exactly you mean? Do you mean StarCraft or StarCraft 2?

Comment: Definitely starcraft 2, since starcraft only ever had one expansion.

Comment: Oh, so this is about SC2 multiplayer? Please, Zeus, improve your question and provide more info. I play SC2 and I had no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to custom. Click melee. You will see two droplist. The left droplist let you pick which expansion you want to play with.

This change was made because of going free to play for most contents. So it no longer make sense to still have a gameplay option.

Source: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/21183638

> The Wings of Liberty, Heart of the Swarm, and Legacy of the Void ladders have now been consolidated into a single ladder using units, balance, and data from Legacy of the Void.
>
> The Expansion Level selection for Wings of Liberty or Heart of the Swarm balance games has been moved to Custom > Melee.

Comment: So you can get teamed up with f2p players without the expansion even tho you have the expansion, in for example ranked teams?

Comment: @Zeus The SC2 multiplayer content is now free for all players, but you were always able to join a friend's party who had expansions that you didn't have.